# Theano shared variable update causes `ValueError: length not known`

Tags: python, numpy, theano

Minimal example code:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x = T.dscalars('x')
z = th.shared(np.zeros(2))
updates = [z, z+x]

f1 = th.function(inputs=[x], updates=updates) 
f1(3)
print z.get_value()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/temp2/theano.test.py", line 9, in <module>
    f1 = th.function(inputs=[x], updates=updates) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 205, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 460, in pfunc
    no_default_updates=no_default_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 191, in rebuild_collect_shared
    for (store_into, update_val) in iter_over_pairs(updates):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 1610, in __iter__
    for i in xrange(get_vector_length(self)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 5210, in get_vector_length
    raise ValueError("length not known")
ValueError: length not known
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Updates` must contain `a list of pairs`. See official tutorial on [using shared variables](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#using-shared-variables).

Correct code:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x = T.dscalars('x')
z = th.shared(np.zeros(2))
updates = [(z, z+x)]

f1 = th.function(inputs=[x], updates=updates) 
f1(3)
print z.get_value()
```

Comment: I'll update the message error in that case to: "The updates parameter must an OrderedDict/dict or a list of list/tuple with 2 elements"

Comment: @nouiz If one tries something like `updates = (z, z+x)` the error message is also not too helpful: `TypeError: TensorType does not support iteration. Maybe you are using builtin.sum instead of theano.tensor.sum? (Maybe .max?)`